# Queries involving a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that stores information about artists, bands and albums and I'm trying to select the band names and album titles for bands with more than 1 album.

```
band_id, name, year_formed
1, blink182, 1990
2, fall out boy, 1997
3, u2, 1982
4, coldplay, 1990
5, zach brown band, 2002
```

and album

```
album_id, title, band_id
1, take off your pants and jack it, 1
2, stars, 3
3, fbgm, 3
4, reach, 3
5, yup, 4
```

This doesn't seem too hard of a problem but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.
The problem seems to be with getting both the album title and band name from the select statement.

```
SELECT b.name, alb.title
FROM band as b, album as alb
WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM album as al WHERE b.bid = alb.bid)
```

Returns the all band names and their album titles. My guess is to have the subquery handle finding the bands with more than one album but I just am at a complete loss for how to do this. Subqueries have been throwing me for a loop in general, so any nice description of how they work conceptually would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `EXISTS`, I think you're looking to use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT b.name, a.title
FROM band b 
    JOIN album a ON b.bid = a.bid
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

If you're looking for the bands with more than a single title, then you'll need to use an aggregate query as well:

```
SELECT b.name, a.title
FROM band b 
    JOIN album a ON b.band_id = a.band_id 
    JOIN (SELECT band_id
          FROM album
          GROUP BY band_id 
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) c ON b.band_id = c.band_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT b.name,x.title  AS Title
FROM band  b LEFT JOIN ( SELECT band_id
                              , GROUP_CONCAT(title SEPARATOR ', ') AS Title
                         FROM album 
                         GROUP BY band_id 
                         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x ON b.band_id = x.band_id 
WHERE x.band_id IS NOT NULL
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c564/17)

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks! Any reason why I should specifically use a left join?

Comment: @user95420 : There could be records in the `album` table that are not present in the `band` table and vice versa, so with `INNER JOIN` this records are not taking in consideration. Logically it quite ok, but considering data integrity it is better to use `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query. You need to use `group_concat()` with a `JOIN` to get you all the titles. See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d689/3.

```
select b.name,tab.new_title
from band b
inner join
(
  select `band_id`, 
  group_concat(`title`) as new_title
from album
group by `band_id`
having count(*) > 1
 ) tab on b.`band_id` = tab.`band_id`
```